# Can we update or delete the VSTS-Git configuration from Azure Data Factory?

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

We have to configure a vsts git to ADF for the deployment. I want to edit the collaboration branch. How can we do that? Below is the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can delete the git and re-add it. Go to the overview page first and then click the git button at the right top corner.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the collaboration branch. There are two options.

1. Remove your git and re-add it again. You have the chance to specify the new collaboration branch during the add process.
2. You could do this in azure portal. (portal.azure.com) In your data factory tags, remove and re-create the  **gitRepoCollaborationBranch** tag.

Currently, author & monitor module doesn't support edit collaboration branch.